# Adapting a Fortran Code to write a file, run an executable and read in arrays from a file

Tags: fortran

I am new to Fortran but I am trying to adapt a Fortran code and I am having trouble doing something which I think is probably quite simple.

I want to adapt a Fortran file called original.f so that it makes an input file called input.inp and populates it with 4 integers calculated earlier in original.f so that input.inp looks like, for example:

```
    &input
        A = 1
        B = 2
        C = 3
        D = 4
    &end
```

I know how to write this format:

```
    OPEN(UNIT=10,FILE='input.inp')
    WRITE (10,00001) 1,2,3,4
    ...
    ...
    ...
    00001 Format (/2x,'&input',
         &        /2x,'A = ',i4,
         &        /2x,'B = ',i4,
         &        /2x,'C = ',i4,
         &        /2x,'D = ',i4,
         &        /2x,'&end')
```

(or something like this that I can fiddle with when I get it working) but I am not sure how to create the input.inp file write this into it and then use this input file.

The input file needs to be used to run an executable called "exec". I would run this in bash as:

```
    ./exec < input.inp > output.out
```

Where output.out contains two arrays called eg(11) and ai(11,6,2) (with dimensions given) like:

```
    eg(1)= 1
    eg(2)= 2
    ...
    ...
    ...
    eg(11)= 11
    ai(1,1,1)= 111
    ai(1,2,1)= 121
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ai(11,6,2)=1162
```

Finally I need to read these inputs back into original.f so that they can be used further down in file. I have defined these arrays at the beginning of original.f as:

```
    COMMON /DATA  / eg(11),ai(11,6,2)
```

But I am not sure of the Fortran to read data line by linw from output.out to populate these arrays.

Any help for any of the stages in this process would be hugely appreciated.

Thank you very much

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the expanded question correctly, you have to work with an output file, produced by some other code you did not write, with lines like `eg(1) = ...`.

For the simplest case where you know the number of elements and their ordering beforehand, you can simply search each line for the equals sign from behind:

```
program readme
  implicit none
  character(100) :: buffer
  integer :: i, j, k, pos, eg(11), ai(11,6,2)

  do i = 1,11
    read*, buffer
    pos = index(buffer, '=', back = .true.)
    read(buffer(pos+1:), *) eg(i)
  enddo

  ! I have assumed an arbitrary ordering here
  do k = 1,2
    do i = 1,11
      do j = 1,6
        read*, buffer
        pos = index(buffer, '=', back = .true.)
        read(buffer(pos+1:), *) ai(i,j,k)
      enddo
    enddo
  enddo 
end program
```

Assuming here for simplicity that the data are provided to standard input.

Comment: Also, please avoid torturing yourself with Fortran 77 if you can. Things like `COMMON` blocks are very old-fashioned and one can write much clearer and less error-prone code with Fortran 90+ syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have shown how you create the input file, I assume the question is how to read it. The code shows how "a" and "b" can be read from successive lines after skipping the first line. On Windows, if the resulting executable is a.exe, the commands a.exe < data.txt or type data.txt | a.exe will read from data.txt.

```
program xread
implicit none
character (len=10) :: words(3)
integer, parameter :: iu = 5 ! assuming unit 5 is standard input
integer            :: a,b
read (iu,*) ! skip line with &input
read (iu,*) words ! read "a", "=", and "1" into 3 strings
read (words(3),*) a ! read integer from 3rd string
read (iu,*) words ! read "b", "=", and "1" into 3 strings 
read (words(3),*) b ! read integer from 3rd string
print*,"a =",a," b =",b
end program xread
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. What I need to do with the input.inp file is actually to use it as the input for an executable stored in the same directory as original.f called 'exec' to produce an output that is then read by original.f. Is this something which is possible?

Comment: The reason I explained how I was writing the input.inp file is just to explain the whole process I am trying to complete to make sure the process makes sense.

Comment: @James: Yes it is, but it's considerably easier if you know the ordering of the elements in the output file beforehand, and therefore do not need to scan for the array indices. Is this the case?